# Run a SQL Query with a function in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am making a website using vb.net and I am trying to populate a CheckBoxList with movie titles. The user will enter a movie title and I will use a function to find the top 10 closest movie titles. The function uses the Lenenshtein Distance algorithm which compares two strings and returns how many different characters need to be swapped to make them the same string. Example: searchValue="Interstellar" compared to "Cinderella" result 5 character changes to make them match.

I want to return the resultset and insert the movie_title into a checkboxlist text and movieID in the value.

My vb.net code that I am using to run this query is:

```
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("MyConnectionString")
    Dim dtMovieSearchResults As New DataTable


    Dim daSearchDiff As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 10 *, [dbo].[FN_Levenshtein_Distance](movie_title, @searchValue) diff FROM ML_Movie ORDER BY diff", con)

    With daSearchDiff.SelectCommand.Parameters
        .Clear()
        .AddWithValue("@searchValue", Convert.ToString(txtSearchMovie.Text))
    End With
    Try
        If ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
        daSearchDiff.Fill(dtMovieSearchResults)

        With cblFoundMovies
            .DataSource = dtMovieSearchResults
            .DataTextField = "movie_title"
            .DataValueField = "movie_id"
            .DataBind()
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
```

This fails and says that the connection has timed out after only a few seconds. Other database queries do work, the problem seems to be related to running a function within the query. Yet the query works fine in SSMS.

I have not found a specific solution to this online and am hoping someone here could help

Comment: For the record, this is a far more appropriate question than your previous attempt. I don't have an answer or time to work one out right now but I wanted to make it clear that I wasn't just trying to be mean before. That question genuinely wasn't good by SO standards, where this one is.

Comment: I appreciate you clarifying. I will be sure to add the problematic code in the future so that my question doesn't seem as open-ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tydied up a bit adding Using...End Using blocks to close and dispose connections and commands. I had to guess at the datatype and field size so, check the database and add the actual type and size.

I really don't see a problem with your code since the query runs in SSMS. I removed the Try...End Try temporarily so you can see exactly where is breaks.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    Dim dtMovieSearchResults As New DataTable
    Using con As New SqlConnection("MyConnectionString"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 10 *, [dbo].[FN_Levenshtein_Distance](movie_title, @searchValue) diff FROM ML_Movie ORDER BY diff", con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchValue", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtSearchMovie.Text
        con.Open()
        dtMovieSearchResults.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    With cblFoundMovies
        .DataSource = dtMovieSearchResults
        .DataTextField = "movie_title"
        .DataValueField = "movie_id"
        .DataBind()
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you! I was ready to remove this feature for now. I also found a way to shave a few seconds off my Function. But I think my problem may have been the way I was adding Parameters. Your answer was extremely helpful, thank you very much for your time